# FuelPhP: How can I add to a Session (Array/Map) Variable?

Tags: php, session, fuelphp

Currently I am working on a simple shopping cart application. I have a form that accepts user input (quantity) for an item. On submission I am taken to the following action (just the framework atm):

```
public function action_setquantity($flower_id) {
$doit = Input::post('doit');
$tf = Input::post('tf');
//$tf is ok (validated), create the cart data

$mycart[$flower_id] = $tf;

//This is only allowing 1 item to be written to Session var 'cart'
Session::set('cart', $mycart);

return Response::redirect("/show/cart"); }
```

Now, my problem is creating an array/mapping of the quantity/item pairs. As the code is now, the Session variable 'cart' is going to be overwritten each time the user uses the form. How can I fix the current logic to continually add mappings to this Session variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply fetch the session value first and add to that before reassigning it.

```
// Default to an empty array so we have a sensible value to work with.
$mycart = Session::get('cart', []);

// TODO: Modify cart data as required here.

// When done reassign the cart data to the session.
Session::set('cart', $mycart);
```

Comment: This is the best answer